# Complex Selectors with jQuery Delegate

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors, jquery-1.4

Is there a restriction on the complexity of selectors that can be used with delegate in jQuery 1.4.2?

This works for me:

```
   $('.activeTabsList').delegate('.activeTabsListItem', 'click', 
function() { 
   alert('here'); 
});
```

This does not work:

```
    $('.activeTabsList').delegate('.activeTabsListItem:not(.selected)', 'click', 
function() { 
   alert('here'); 
});
```

As you can probably assume, there is only 1 item at a time that has the selected class. When I click the other tabs, my delegate handler is still not fired.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The code you have works, [you can see a demo here](http://jsfiddle.net/bLw4N/).  Make sure that your selector matches like you think it does, this is most likely the issue...[`.delegate()`](http://api.jquery.com/delegate/) itself handles this case.

Usually this happens as a result of something like this, over-assigning the `selected` class:

```
$(".activeTabsListItem").click(function() {
  $(".activeTabsListItem").addClass("selected"); //should have been $(this)
});
```

Comment: Thanks - just making sure I wasn't trying to do something unsupported before I really try to look into it deeper. None of the demos cover anything beyond simple selectors. I've never seen jsFiddle, but that's a pretty sweet tool

Comment: +1 for the answer....if I could give another for the link to jsFiddle, I would...nice tool!

Comment: My problem ended up being because I am using this with the ui tabs. That fires first so my tab is always selected by the time my event fires.